# DNS server won't work! [Bind9 running on Debian 7; virtualized through Proxmox 3.1]

Tags: linux, networking, dns, ip, bind

First I'd like to thank everyone in advance for helping me - communities like this are exactly what amatuers like myself need when faced with perplexing issues.

I've recently begun virtualizing servers - on of which is a dns server running bind9 on debian 7.  My dhcp server correctly issues it as the primary dns for the network, but I just can't seem to get head or tail of why it isn't working.  Feel free to ask me for more info

Zone file (the email has been changed to hide my personal info)

```
; BIND data file for kilraine zone
;
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     kilraine.lan. myaddress.myemail.com. (
                     2014060303         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL

        IN      A       192.168.1.2
;
@       IN      NS      dns.kilraine.lan
@       IN      A       192.168.1.2

dns2    IN      A       192.168.1.1
dns     IN      A       192.168.1.2
dhcp    IN      A       192.168.1.3
main    IN     A      192.168.1.10
```

Reverse zone file

```
;
; BIND reverse data file for kilraine.lan
;
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     kilraine.lan. myaddress.myemail.com. (
                     3006201401         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@       IN      NS      dns.
1       IN      PTR     dns2.kilraine.lan
2       IN      PTR     dns.kilraine.lan
3       IN      PTR     dhcp.kilraine.lan
10      IN      PTR     main.kilraine.lan
```

And lastly my named.conf.local file.

```
//
// Do any local configuration here
//

// Consider adding the 1918 zones here, if they are not used in your
// organization
// include "/etc/bind/zones.rfc1918";

zone "kilraine.lan" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/db.kilraine.lan";
};

zone "1.168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/db.192";
};
```

I have restarted bind9 numerous times, and I have always gotten "OK".  I used the dnsutils tool 'dig' on both the server and a client, each return the following

```
    ; <<>> DiG 9.8.4-rpz2+rl005.12-P1 <<>> kilraine.lan
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 46467
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;kilraine.lan.          IN  A

;; Query time: 2 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.1.2#53(192.168.1.2)
;; WHEN: Mon Jun 30 21:53:41 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 30
```

I get the following error if I try to use dig kilraine.lan @dns.kilraine.lan

```
couldn't get address for 'dns.kilraine.lan': not found
```

Though I get the original dig output from "dig kilraine.lan @192.168.1.2"

Thanks - I REALLY appreciate any help!  Please, don't hesitate for more info!!!